# In Blender 2.79 what does it mean to add a Material Node that reverences itself?

Tags: shader-nodes

So I came across a Material in Blender 2.79 that is using the new [Material Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/index.html).

The surprising thing is that it is using a [Material Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/types/input/material.html) that is using itself in the
drop down field.

This looks to me like it should result in an endless loop. But it doesn't...

So what does it mean in Blender 2.79 if a Material in Shader-Node-Form uses itself as a Material Node ?

Any answers would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: That's a Blender Internal material, it is not "using itself" that is a material node containing a datablock called "*ReplacementMat...*". This is how they used to work before there was a concept of a "Shader Node", if you wanted to optionally use nodes in your material, you had one or several of these *Material Nodes*  mixed together.

Comment: Yes, but I can use a Material Node using ReplacementMaterial inside my ReplacementMaterial Material... How does that not result in an infinite loop ?